# ajax filter is used to filter product but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in JavaScript. I have problem with ajax filter. Following is my script code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        filter_data();

        function filter_data()
        {
            var action = 'fetch_data.php';
            var size = get_filter('size');
            var color = get_filter('color');
            var brand = get_filter('brand');

            $.ajax({
                alert("Hello");
                url:"fetch_data",
                method:"POST",
                data:{action:action,size:size,color:color,brand:brand},
                success:function(data){
                    $('.filter_data').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function get_filter(class_name)
        {
            var filter=[];
            $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
                filter.push($(this).val());
            });
            return filter;
        }

        $('.common_selector').click(function(){
            filter_data();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I used this references

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

alter is just for error test. please fix my error sir. Thanks

Comment: `url:"fetch_data",` is `fetch_data` a valid url/script? What errors do you get? Use your browsers devtools (Network and Console) to see if any errors occur

Comment: it should be ```url:"fetch_data.php"```, can you share your HTML code as well

Comment: HTML code is very long. there is no error in HTML code. $.ajax({}) only that part doesn't work.

Comment: I think there may something wrong with references. But I don't know